# Reference and populate from various collections in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This might be a somewhat contrived example but lets say I have a mongodb database with schemas for tags, blog posts and people. I want to be able to use the same type of tags e.g "programming", "javascript" for both blog posts and people. I also want the tag to "own" the relationship, i.e. I want to put the reference to the blog post/person in the tag schema and let blog post/person be unaware of tag.

With **mongodb** this seems to be solvable by using [dbrefs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref). However, I haven't found out how to do it in **mongoose**. Basically I want to fetch a tag and populate `taggedElements` with the schema below. But how would I define the schema in mongoose and how would I populate the fields from different collections?

```
tagSchema = {
    name : String,
    taggedElements : [
        // how to define this?
    ]
```

Comment: You may want to see here https://github.com/goulash1971/mongoose-dbref